# How can I set up a purely front-end web project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Quite a few of the projects I make are purely front-end web applications: that is, purely JS/HTML/CSS, no ASP.NET or any sort of backend server behavior.

I like using Visual Studio to write and debug these projects, but I can't figure out how to make an entirely front-end project.

Up to date, I've just created an empty ASP.NET solution and just ignored all the parts that I don't need, but I don't really like doing it that way.

I've also just opened the files I need to edit in Visual Studio, but for some reason the Visual Studio debugger is disabled when I do this.

Is there a good way to create a purely front-end web project in Visual Studio?

Comment: I think this is the closest you can get

[Opening a folder as website](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13294839/205859)