# Open a folder in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am creating an Angular project but I love the features of Visual Studio 2012. I am looking for an option to open the folder in Visual Studio 2012 (Similar to "Open Folder" option in Sublime text), which will list all the contents of the folder. Currently, I am navigating the files in windows explorer and opening them in Visual Studio as I need them.

One of the options I can think of is to create a project (for e.g. Console application) and add these files and folder into that, but I will not compile the project.

Just wondering if there is a better way (a VS template that I am not aware of) or a hidden option somewhere in VS.

Comment: If you figured out your answer you should add it as an answer to your question, then when the system lets you can mark it as the answer. That way the question will show as being answered.

Comment: Thanks @MarkHall I will do that. I tried it now and it said I need to wait for 8 hours before answering my own question. So I will do that in the morning.

Comment: You may also want to check AngularJS starter kit for Visual Studio: http://github.com/kriasoft/angular-vs

Comment: Excellent thanks Grief Coder, I will check it out.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Solution 
 File -> Open Website -> File System and choose the folder. 
No extra project or solution file. VS just opens the folder as it is.

**This solution still valid even in Visual Studio 2017 community**

Comment: Works in VS 2019

Answer (score 2):

There is an other option now and that is to use Visual Studio Code. It is much more lightweight, supported by Microsoft and is very well suited for js development including angular.

Otherwise in Visual Studio 2017 it's possible to open a folder directly now:

[image: Open folder]

You can find more details in [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#open-folder).

Answer (score 0):

The key is to look on the right side and make sure on the bottom you're on the "Solution Explorer" tab.  You'll see all your folders/code files listed there.